# EF CTP code-first The type initializer for 'Foo' threw an exception

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, .net-4.0, code-first

> File already exists. Try using a different database name. [ File name = F:\foo.sdf ]

This shouln't happen when using `this.Database.CreateIfNotExists()` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was caused by EFCTP4 when updated the packages to [EFCTP5](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/08/announcing-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-release.aspx) started working again.